# Reasons for : xxx.aspx has not been pre-compiled and cannot be requested (it is pre-compiled)

Tags: asp.net, iis, compilation

hoping someone has some insight into this issue I get pretty commonly.
I have an ASPX Web Application that is pre-compiled. I have this application running within another IIS application working flawlessly. The parent application has an "updatable=false" property within the PreCompiledapp.config.

Now I need to add more pages to my application, which I create the same way in visual studio, and publish them with the rest of the application. When I open these files to check them in notepad, I can see the "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!" as well as the .compiled file that generates with it.

On a local machine and application instance, this works... but when I copy the same applicaiton build to a client (same application, same pages, same everything) it gives me the " xxx.aspx has not been pre-compiled and cannot be requested " error.

What could be some causes of this? The pages are pre-compiled so I'm wondering if this can be thrown for something else. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause may be the parent application is set with `updatable=false` but the ASPX Web Application which you published is allow update. So it may lead to this problem. The same error message and the cause are described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/asiatech/the-file-xxxxxx-aspx-has-not-been-pre-compiled-and-cannot-be-requested).

To solve this problem is convert your application to web application(has its own AppDomain and configuration) or publish the root application as updatable as well.